# Re-link symbols so 'Jump To Definition' works in Xcode 4.6

Tags: xcode, documentation, xcode4.6

I recently trashed my Xcode 4.6.3 and download its replacement from the App Store. Now I can't access symbols for definitions via 'Jump To Definition' contextual menu.

I get 'Symbol Not Found'; ALL THE TIME!

Is there a way to re-index everything so Xcode 4.6.3. is aware?

Comment: Did you try clean and build?

Comment: Yes I tried it, but yet I get an error 'Symbol Not Found'.

Answer (score 3):

What I did for Xcode 7.3:

1. close Xcode
2. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`
3. `rm -rf project.xcworkspace` (in your .xcodeproj)
4. `rm -rf xcuserdata` (in your .xcodeproj)
5. open Xcode. you need to wait for the indexing finished
6. profit!!!

My symptom is that all "jump to definition" failed even for hello world projects.
After resetting everything , it works again ^_^

Answer (score 1):

To make Xcode rebuild the index for a project, you need to delete the project's Derived Data.

From the menu bar, choose Window > Organizer.  In the Organizer window, choose the Projects tab.  Find your project in the list on the left.  Click the “Delete…” button to the right of the Derived Data path for the project.

[image: Derived Data delete button]

Comment: I have tried this but still I am getting an error 'Symbol Not Found'.